# PL/Sql dbms_xmlgen.getxml not returning all table columns in XML output

Tags: sql, oracle, dbms-xmlgen

I am trying to extract Oracle table data in XML format using the DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE libraries. With my SQL described below; I get the output in the format I want but XML generator skipped the last column output. It happens to be the LONG data type, which is what I wrote this format of SQL.

```
   { CREATE TABLE SYSADM.PS_SPEEDCHART_HDR
     (
       SETID VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       SPEEDCHART_KEY VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT 
       NULL,
       OPRID VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       OPRCLASS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       EFFDT DATE NOT NULL,
       EFF_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       DESCR VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       SPEEDTYPE_TYPE VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       TOTAL_LINES INTEGER NOT NULL,
       UNIT_OF_MEASURE VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT 
       NULL,
       SPDCHRT_DEFN_FLG VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT 
       NULL,
       DESCRLONG LONG
       );
```

Comment: Sorry, my complete question didn't appear. Here's the re-post.

Comment: Why are you creating a table with a LONG column? You should be using CLOB. It also might be helpful to show your code.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am pulling data from a database where data is in LONG field; converting to another DB with CLOB fields. This is what I am doing.. I may have to post my code with multiple comments. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: -- Insert data script
SET DEFINE OFF;

Insert into PS_SPEEDCHART_HDR
   (SETID, SPEEDCHART_KEY, OPRID, OPRCLASS, EFFDT, 
    EFF_STATUS, DESCR, SPEEDTYPE_TYPE, TOTAL_LINES, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
    SPDCHRT_DEFN_FLG, DESCRLONG)
 Values
   ('XYZ', '05663', ' ', ' ', TO_DATE('01/01/2000 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'A', 'WX DOE 06 SUBRECIPIENT TRVL', 'U', 1, ' ', 'P', ' ');
COMMIT;

Comment: -- Select data in XML format
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('select * from PS_SPEEDCHART_HDR').getclobval (),
                   CHR (38),
                   CHR (38) || 'amp;')
                   AS XML_output
           FROM DUAL)

Comment: -- XML output
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <SETID>TDHCA</SETID>
  <SPEEDCHART_KEY>05663</SPEEDCHART_KEY>
  <OPRID> </OPRID>
  <OPRCLASS> </OPRCLASS>
  <EFFDT>01-JAN-00</EFFDT>
  <EFF_STATUS>A</EFF_STATUS>
  <DESCR>WX DOE 06 SUBRECIPIENT TRVL</DESCR>
  <SPEEDTYPE_TYPE>U</SPEEDTYPE_TYPE>
  <TOTAL_LINES>1</TOTAL_LINES>
  <UNIT_OF_MEASURE> </UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
  <SPDCHRT_DEFN_FLG>P</SPDCHRT_DEFN_FLG>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>

<DESCRLONG> is missing

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51413433/edit) to add all of that, as formatted text